# Proper approach to test inbound emails on localhost

Tags: php, email, cakephp, sendgrid, ngrok

I am currently working on a legacy CakePHP application that needs to to able to receive and parse emails using Sendgrid Webhooks. My team does it's development locally on our laptops and utilizes web servers for testing.

This feature should be able to receive an email from from an email client (gmail, etc.), parse it out and create items in the database based off of the email's contents. I am wondering what the most strait forward approach would be to test something like this locally while in development or if I am better off developing this on one of our servers in AWS? I am currently looking at Ngrok following [this tutorial](https://sendgrid.com/blog/test-webhooks-ngrok/), but it is a bit dated and I wonder if there is a better way to handle this.

Also looking at using [Mail Mine Parser for PHP](https://github.com/zbateson/mail-mime-parser), on the application side. If you happen to know of something better I would certainly be interested to know about it.

Thanks in advance for any feedback on the subject!

Comment: maybe easiest just installing a local mail server? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Hope help you - https://mailtrap.io/

Comment: @Dmitry, I am familiar with with mailtrap.io. Although I thought it was more for catching and testing outbound emails from the application. My use case is sending emails from an email client like Gmail to the application and having the application parse them. If mailtrap.io has any functionality that aids with that, I have not seen it yet and would certainly appreciate being directed towards it.

Comment: I know that it's possible to create via DB. In this way I've created Oracle email parsing system. For this you need to know connection ip / port etc. If you're using another DB - try to find info how to get access to the emailbox and how to retrieve data from it. Parsing is the last part of this job. Firstly, get the access and try to retrieve count of email-letters at least.

Comment: @Dmitry Mailtrap, mailhog, and mailcatcher, are for outbound mail. He needs a mail server installed

Comment: why would you want to test wether Gmail is sending mails correctly anyway? Why not send the mail to another gmail account then use their mail API (I assume they have one) to fetch the mails?

Comment: yes they have one https://developers.google.com/gmail/api

Comment: @delboy1978uk I am not testing the mail client (Gmail, etc), but what my application is doing with the incoming email. I am going to need to be setting data in the headers, subjects, etc. that the application will need to parse and intemperate properly.

Comment: How will your application fetch the email from the actual email server?

Comment: @delboy1978uk I am still figuring that out, but it looks like that would be handled by the PHP plugin I shared in the question. Although you can correct me if I am wrong. https://github.com/zbateson/mail-mime-parser

Comment: My point is, you could use the Gmail API to fetch mails from them, and send the mails to there instead. Then you can easily fetch using like i said their API, OR, if you won't be using Gmail, a generic lib like https://packagist.org/packages/rdx/imap . Then you can get on with the coding you WANT to do! :-P

Comment: So the mail server can be anywhere, you just need to connect to it

Comment: @delboy1978uk So what your saying is that for testing my features I can integrate the Gmail API which will allow me to fetch emails sent to the application in php. Essentially the Gmail API would be acting as a mail server of sorts? I am wondering how this would scale to receiving email from other email clients, like Outlook. I am not overly familiar with what Gmail API does, I am looking into it more now.

Comment: For testing what your application does when it connects to a mail server to read emails, what you are going to want to do is connect to a mail server to read emails...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handled a similar task using sengrid inbound webhooks and ngrok. The latter allows you to expose a public url on your local laptop/machine where sendgrid can send incoming emails. 
Please check:

https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/parsing-email/setting-up-the-inbound-parse-webhook

https://ngrok.com

I would suggest you test your webhook using ngrok before you set-up your own inbound webhook server.